# Как правильно узнать время исполнения?

Tags: qt, время

Не знаю как правильно считать потраченное время для вывода его на экран монитора.

Я воспользовался библиотекой QTimer но так и не смог вызвать значение таймера, по прерываниям он прекрасно работает.

Есть библиотека QTime но она берет время от операционной системы, что мне не особо нравится ибо это завязка важного элемента на работу из вне. Есть ещё библиотека Chrono из С++ , но она весьма тяжёлая для восприятия.

Вот код

mainwindows.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    timers[0] = new QTimer(this);
    timers[1] = new QTimer(this);

    connect(timers[0],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD1_timer_0()));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(HREN()),this,SLOT(wizow_hreni()));

    timers[0]->start(1000);
    timers[1]->start();
}

void MainWindow::DD1_timer_0()
{
   int i =  ui->pB_hren->value() + 1;
   ui->pB_hren->setValue(i);
   if(i == 75)
       HREN();
}

void MainWindow::wizow_hreni()
{
    ui->pB_DD5->setValue(1000);
    ui->pB_DD5->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;"
                                   "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                                   "border-radius: 5px;"
                                   "border-width: 3px;"
                                   "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                   "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                    "}"
                                   "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
    ui->pB_DD5->setFormat(" неисправен ");

    // timers[1] почемуто не получаеться получить время с таймера
    // что бы вывести "потраченное" время (ui->label_3->) 
}
```

---

вот мнемосхема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону ``QElapsedTimer``, он как раз предназначен для измерения временных интервалов.

Comment: Чем не устраивает `QTime::elapsed()`?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver QTime завязан на операционку

Comment: Весь фреймворк "завязан на операционку"

Comment: @BeardedBeaver так как тогда работать с сверх точным временем и с в режиме реального времени ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо @Александр,  QElapsedTimer прекрасно подошло.

mainwindows.h

```
QTimer * timers[2];
QElapsedTimer* timer;
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ...
    timers[0] = new QTimer(this);
    timer = new QElapsedTimer(this);

    connect(timers[0],SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DD1_timer_0()));

    connect(this,SIGNAL(HREN()),this,SLOT(wizow_hreni()));

    timers[0]->start(1000);
    timer->start();
}

void MainWindow::DD1_timer_0()
{
   int i =  ui->pB_hren->value() + 1;
   ui->pB_hren->setValue(i);
   if(i == 75)
       HREN();
}

void MainWindow::wizow_hreni()
{
    ui->pB_DD5->setValue(1000);
    ui->pB_DD5->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar{border: 1px solid transparent;text-align: center;"
                                   "color:rgba(255,255,250,255);"
                                   "border-radius: 5px;"
                                   "border-width: 3px;"
                                   "border-image: 9,2,5,2; "
                                   "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 200), stop:1 rgba(0, 0, 0, 200));"
                                    "}"
                                   "QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(255,200,0,255), stop: 1 rgba(255,0,0,255));}");
    ui->pB_DD5->setFormat(" неисправен ");

    ui->label_3->setNum((double)timer->elapsed()); // прекрасно отработал
}
```